# Miner address is all zero in block

Tags: go-ethereum

I sent a transaction in clique POA private chain and get the block via transaction hash.
Why is the miner address for this transaction all zero?

**step 1: send a transaction**

```
> eth.sendTransaction({from:'0x558dfdb706847de650dfbdc19c5295c6fe29dab5',to:'0x6bcb6fdd4fe6d8d2eafa30ffbf7d1e663231403f',value:web3.toWei(1,"ether")})
"0x6f75c39f98f18ce6faf02e46d4bd53c2ce5f40549ec62410c560ad59bd172e39"
```

**step 2 get block via transaction hash**

```
> eth.getTransaction("0x6f75c39f98f18ce6faf02e46d4bd53c2ce5f40549ec62410c560ad59bd172e39")
{
  blockHash: "0xbf2d253c1171cd9da45472fa2e92a8d4a71a6a836b80b922a808ca88e8ec9a7b",
  blockNumber: 56624,
  from: "0x558dfdb706847de650dfbdc19c5295c6fe29dab5",
  gas: 21000,
  gasPrice: 1000000000,
  hash: "0x6f75c39f98f18ce6faf02e46d4bd53c2ce5f40549ec62410c560ad59bd172e39",
  input: "0x",
  nonce: 76,
  r: "0x14fbadd027575b9bb15859844332410517a0379a275b4795c740df8667abaefa",
  s: "0x361990e6c38be3de787cedfb989244a7474d89e8d38dc8a68cc00d7695215b20",
  to: "0x6bcb6fdd4fe6d8d2eafa30ffbf7d1e663231403f",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0x3dd4",
  value: 1000000000000000000
}
```

**step 3: get block details via block number**

```
> eth.getBlock(56624)
{
  difficulty: 2,
  extraData: "0xd883010900846765746888676f312e31322e34856c696e75780000000000000089d9d6ebb23327af16c483814c1372ee4a1ee7295bae5994ae09447bf000a6ca0bad468ab3c3e1fd8308a63fb7b29bd95fcd5b7a66971516543115826272c4cd00",
  gasLimit: 8000000,
  gasUsed: 21000,
  hash: "0xbf2d253c1171cd9da45472fa2e92a8d4a71a6a836b80b922a808ca88e8ec9a7b",
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  miner: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  mixHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  nonce: "0x0000000000000000",
  number: 56624,
  parentHash: "0xa70805ba45bea2368317991f8b02b27c966808960045f161179f0c647a022440",
  receiptsRoot: "0x056b23fbba480696b65fe5a59b8f2148a1299103c4f57df839233af2cf4ca2d2",
  sha3Uncles: "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
  size: 722,
  stateRoot: "0x4ff9ded28f68dc9f77770da8a6c73a9999fa2eadf79b2a111f4e589e95dd5299",
  timestamp: 1558403220,
  totalDifficulty: 113249,
  transactions: ["0x6f75c39f98f18ce6faf02e46d4bd53c2ce5f40549ec62410c560ad59bd172e39"],
  transactionsRoot: "0x2b429c381013191e134b9db2f0863075aea8ba066a19d205d91697016fbc7147",
  uncles: []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your suggestion to use `"ecrecover"` function run on a private POA ethereum chain, the result shows a wrong miner address, not the actual miner address.
Thanks for you help.

```
calculated miner address : "0x9a1da187d501ea796599dd0e2c9de52b1b1a3794"
actual miner address: "0x3c46b43e683b5addd7e66b3d1d958854ffb58361"
```

**geth version**

```
Version: 1.8.27-stable
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.12.4
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=/root/goworks
GOROOT=/usr/local/go
```

**node version**
`10.15.3`

**miner address resolving code**

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const utils = require('ethereumjs-util');
const BlockHeader = require('ethereumjs-block/header');
const web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545');
const main = async () => {
const block = await web3.eth.getBlock(7);
const dataBuff = utils.toBuffer(block.extraData);
const sig = utils.fromRpcSig(dataBuff.slice(dataBuff.length - 65, dataBuff.length));
block.extraData = '0x' + utils.toBuffer(block.extraData).slice(0, dataBuff.length - 65).toString('hex');
console.log("got extraData = ",block.extraData);
const headerHash = new BlockHeader({
    parentHash: utils.toBuffer(block.parentHash),
    uncleHash: utils.toBuffer(block.sha3Uncles),
    coinbase: utils.toBuffer(block.miner),
    stateRoot: utils.toBuffer(block.stateRoot),
    transactionsTrie: utils.toBuffer(block.transactionsRoot),
    receiptTrie: utils.toBuffer(block.receiptsRoot),
    bloom: utils.toBuffer(block.logsBloom),
    difficulty: utils.toBuffer(block.difficulty),
    number: utils.toBuffer(block.number),
    gasLimit: utils.toBuffer(block.gasLimit),
    gasUsed: utils.toBuffer(block.gasUsed),
    timestamp: utils.toBuffer(block.timestamp),
    extraData: utils.toBuffer(block.extraData),
    mixHash: utils.toBuffer(block.mixHash),
    nonce: utils.toBuffer(block.nonce)
});
const pub = utils.ecrecover(headerHash.hash(), sig.v, sig.r, sig.s);
const address = utils.addHexPrefix(utils.pubToAddress(pub).toString('hex'));
console.log("miner address result:",address) ;
};
main();
```

**block information**

```
> eth.getBlock(7)
{
  difficulty: 2,
  extraData: "0xd88301081b846765746888676f312e31312e39856c696e757800000000000000dd7dbfb525694a880603c92ed9326e2fdd37907ae2d2528b8bb9dc1ae11c605d03868c1644186b84ba300ec8f53681eb479ee2438ebad4f0f77e44a4725c55f401",
  gasLimit: 4732212,
  gasUsed: 0,
  hash: "0x6c9587d64ca2446bd7a6fd9d595e0bdf8af5b9627e7f32455c0f4fb4925ef7ce",
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  miner: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  mixHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  nonce: "0x0000000000000000",
  number: 7,
  parentHash: "0x9e72501d25bb1809b44568c4ec69ebdee92a22d9b05aaf104b5726992b19aba1",
  receiptsRoot: "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",
  sha3Uncles: "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
  size: 606,
  stateRoot: "0xf899500a3ff238853d1c23b73f799135770c1ba16e970f4feff385b7ab777c92",
  timestamp: 1559202842,
  totalDifficulty: 15,
  transactions: [],
  transactionsRoot: "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",
  uncles: []
}
```

Comment: You can edit your own question to add more details. The signature is calculated on the block's hash without the `extraData` field.

Comment: What more information is needed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As part of the changes required by rinkeby some fields from the block headers were repurposed, for more details consult [Clique PoA protocol & Rinkeby PoA testnet](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225).

- `miner` and `nonce` are repurposed to vote for new validator.

  > Should be filled with zeroes normally, modified only while voting.

  When voting `miner` is the address to vote for and `nonce` is the vote

  - `0xffffffffffffffff` to approve validator
  - `0x0000000000000000` to vote for removal

Comment: I check the block info again, the miner and nonce value are still all zeros. the private chain has three nodes, two are sealer, one is normal node(is validator?). when the miner address will be updated to sealer address, not all zeros?

Comment: the new validator you mentioned here is for adding a new sealer?  if the miner field is for this purpose, how can I know the miner address for a specific block?

Comment: Validator/Sealer are nodes than can create new blocks. The `miner` field will be zero unless validators are voting to add or remove another validator with the `clique.propose()` command. To determine the miner/validator the `extraData` field contains a signature which together with the block header data you can use ECRecover to find the validator/sealer.